# Is it possible to add the production version of a React app to a server without Root access?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I'd like to add the production version of this app: https://github.com/Danskii/Toronto-Bike-Fixit-Map/tree/master to my shared hosting server. I do not have root access.

I tried to download the GitHub repo and upload it to the public_html folder to no avail.

Comment: You need to put the contents of the `build` folder into the directory on your server that gets served through http

Comment: You also need to make sure you have a proper `homepage` set in `package.json` when you build.

Comment: Would this need to live in the root of the site or could I put it in a folder. For example my domain is https://danielpuiatti.com/. Would I be able to add the app to https://danielpuiatti.com/bike?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have that as the `homepage`

Comment: As such? "homepage": "https://danielpuiatti.com/Toronto-Bike-Fixit-Map"

Comment: If you want danialpuiatti.com/bike then you need `"homepage": "https://danialpuiatti.com/bike"` (Note the `s` in `https`. If you don't have TLS, it won't work and you'll have to use `http`)

Comment: Is this a static site? If so, just host it on Github and link your url to it.- https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site

Comment: I'd like the app to sit on my domain danielpuiatti.com. I added the build folder contents into the public_html folder and adjusted the "homepage" line in my packadge.json file. No luck: https://danielpuiatti.com/Toronto-Bike-Fixit-Map/